# What is the equivalent terminal command to ipconfig /all?

Tags: command-line, networking, ip

In windows I can use `ipconfig /all` and this displays all the info about my connection.

In terminal using `ifconfig` does not and only supplies limited info. I can use network manager, but it would be useful to know the command line alternative.

So my question is: what is the command line to supply ip address, gateway, subnet mask, DNS  the same way `ipconfig /all` supplies in Windows.

Thanks all

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The only thing missing from ifconfig are the gateway and DNS servers.

### 15.04 and newer

To get the DNS and Gateway info just type:

```
nmcli dev show eth0
```

The output lists some device parameters including some `IP4.DNS[x]` entries, which show the DNS servers and a `IP4.ADDRESS[1]` line which lists the IP and Gateway used (look for the `gw = ???.???.???.???` part at the end of the line up to 15.10). On 16.04 and newer versions there is a `IP4.GATEWAY` line which is pretty self explanatory.

Replace `eth0` with the actual device name you're using, which may not be the same. To get a list of devices and their status type:

```
nmcli dev status
```

### Up to and including 14.10

You can get these with **nm-tool** (in Ubuntu versions **prior to 15.04**) which BTW is the command line version of network manager.

To run it just type in a terminal:

```
nm-tool
```

If you're using Ubuntu **15.04 or newer** the `nm-tool` has been replaced by the `nmcli` command which is different. Check the section called "15.04 and newer" above this one in this case.

Comment: Using `nmcli dev show eth0` results in this: Error: 'dev' command 'show' is not valid.

Comment: @Enkouyami What Ubuntu and nmcli versions are you using?

Comment: @devius nmcli v0.9.8.8 on Ubuntu 15.04.

Comment: @Enkouyami I'm using 0.9.10 and it works just fine. Not sure if this particular command is a new addition or not, but you can try to get help by using `nmcli dev help` to see which commands are available.

Comment: This does not work on Linux Mint 17 based on Ubuntu 14.04. The command to use is `nmcli d list` which shows info for all connections, connected or not.

Comment: just do **nmcli device show**, from there you can get the device name

Answer (score 15):

ipconfig shows things like hostname, DNS servers, those are in a different place than just IP addresses in linux, so you will need a couple of commands.

```
hostname
ifconfig -a
cat /etc/resolv.conf
```

That shows what I want to see 99% of the time, but ipconfig /all also shows things like DHCP lease times and servers.

```
cat /var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.leases
```

Answer (score 4):

Was looking at few links and finally found the below working:

```
nmcli dev list | grep IP4
```

The output is:

```
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         ip = 195.168.0.107/24, gw = 192.168.0.1
IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.0.1
IP4.DOMAIN[1]:                          local
```

Also all the network related details can be found using putting simply:

```
nmcli dev list eth0
```

[ubuntu](/questions/tagged/ubuntu) [chromium](/questions/tagged/chromium)

Comment: `nmcli dev list | grep IP4` means take the output of `nmcli dev list` and then feed it (using the pipe `|`) into `grep` and keep lines that contain regex pattern `IP4`.

Comment: `nmcli dev list | grep IP4` doesn't work on Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 3):

Here's the simplest equivalent i could find for ubuntu 17.04

```
nmcli device show
```

Sample output (ip4 stuff only):

```
nmcli device show | grep IP4
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         172.27.35.55/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            172.27.35.1
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP4.DNS[1]:                             172.27.35.1
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         127.0.0.1/8
IP4.GATEWAY:
```

Comment: Finally! This worked on Ubuntu 21!

Answer (score 2):

I needed to work out what DHCP server I was connected to via Ubuntu 14.04 so I used this command:

```
nmcli dev list|grep DHCP4
```

as this is what I wanted only from the original command "nmcli dev list"

```
DHCP4.OPTION[1]: expiry = 1464073312

DHCP4.OPTION[2]:  domain_name = [omitted_proper_details]

DHCP4.OPTION[3]:  broadcast_address = 10.1.45.255

DHCP4.OPTION[4]:  dhcp_message_type = 5

DHCP4.OPTION[5]:  dhcp_lease_time = 432000

DHCP4.OPTION[6]:  ip_address = 10.1.45.132

DHCP4.OPTION[7]:  subnet_mask = 255.255.255.0

DHCP4.OPTION[8]:  dhcp_renewal_time = 216000

DHCP4.OPTION[9]:  routers = 10.1.45.1

DHCP4.OPTION[10]: domain_name_servers = 10.1.26.10 10.1.20.10

DHCP4.OPTION[11]: dhcp_rebinding_time = 378000

DHCP4.OPTION[12]: network_number = 10.1.45.0

DHCP4.OPTION[13]: dhcp_server_identifier = 10.1.20.10
```

Gives me all the DCHP/DNS details I need, just like `ipconfig /all`